# Connecting from AWS AppFlow to SAP

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, odata, amazon-appflow

I am trying to connect from AWS AppFlow to SAP. For the application host URL, when I use the hostname `https://xxxx-xxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx`  I keep getting the syntax error:

> invalid host url

But when I use the IP address, `https://11.222.333.44` the syntax error goes away but then gets the error

> Error while communicating to connector: Client error: The request to SAP failed with the status code: 400 and error message: Fail to execute GET http request and response: (Service: SandstoneBridgeService; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ConnectorClientException;`

What could be the reason?

Comment: did you followed this tutorial? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appflow/latest/userguide/sapodata.html do you use the correct URL?

Comment: Does your SAP system have a CA-signed certificate?